# shade the area between two line vectors in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am trying to shade the area between two line vectors in MATLAB but it's doing something weird... Here's my code:

```
startDate = datenum('01-01-2004');
endDate = datenum('12-01-2012');
xData = linspace(startDate,endDate,108);
fill( [xData' fliplr(xData')],  [Rain_Max fliplr(Rain_Min)], 'b');
set(gca, 'XTick', xData([1 14 26 38 49 62 74 86 97]));
datetick('x','yyyy','keepticks')
xlim([731947 735204])
```

[image]

What is going on?!

This is what I get when I just plot the two lines:

[image]

```
Rain_Max = [54.3765 71.9412  67.1059 10.6000 13.7765  3.6824   0.3647 0.9647 4.6706 9.9059 16.1647 37.7529 60.1353 34.4235 42.5353 11.9000  7.8000 14.6294 8.4235 5.7706 1.7941 37.3059 30.5765 36.3765  68.5765 38.4588 74.8353 52.9824 4.9412 10.5059 8.1176  2.2824 12.0176 6.0000 13.2706 34.6941 64.0706  53.2706 66.3059 7.3059 10.0000 21.2941  0.7176 13.9941 6.4471 17.2000 23.9176 39.5588 55.8941  67.6353  34.5118  11.9588  5.7529 6.7588 14.8706 0.2471 9.3059 12.6118 32.2000 75.2824 59.7471 72.7706 23.7824 18.3176 23.0176 9.9059 0.5529  0.5294 0.9294 14.4118 14.6000 63.1765 78.3765 60.5882 37.2706 29.5647 14.1176 1.9059 11.2059 21.2471 17.1000  28.5824 32.3353 68.4000 68.7647 83.9765 69.3059 42.6471 7.9529 7.1647 3.8294  3.9176 1.2235 15.3706 31.2176  49.9765 79.8941 54.4412 74.0000 20.8824 10.4235 9.6588 10.3765 0.6471 3.4235 11.6000 23.5235 28.9294];

Rain_Min = [1.2294 1.2412 0.9882 1.6471 2.3412 1.0235 0.1882 0.3647 0.3706 2.7412 2.1294 3.2765 1.6176 1.1824 0.7824 0.5824 2.1176 0.9529 4.3059 0.7765 0.6176 1.8059 0.8000 2.6235 1.6882 1.8176 1.8176 3.0294 0.8118 0.9176 1.3706 0.0941 1.8647 1.8000 0.9706 1.5118 1.9588 1.9059 1.6529 1.5294 1.7176 0.9235 0.3765 2.3529 0.2412 3.8941 1.7294 1.4471 1.2588 1.0471 1.1412 1.8529 0.2471 1.0647 0.6471 0.2471 1.3529 1.3529 2.4706 1.4412 1.5176 1.5765 2.6118 0.8588 1.0000 1.3882 0.2941 0.2941  0.6235 3.2353 5.2647 6.2824 1.1529 1.5235 2.5471  3.0000    2.2471 1.1765 1.7882  5.1294  2.1529 2.1294 3.7882 4.1176 0.9706  1.7176 1.8824 3.5000 2.6765 3.4235 2.9588 0.9529 0.0235  1.8529 1.8353 2.7765 3.8941 1.5294 1.6176 4.4118 2.2824 0.3412 2.9882 0.1647 2.6588 1.5294 5.2471 2.1588];
```

Comment: Please include what `Rain_Max` and `Rain_Min` are so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @rayryeng thanks, I now have included the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do this using `area` with a twist:

```
...
area(xData,[Rain_Min(:) ,  Rain_Max(:)-Rain_Min(:)]); hold on
colormap([1 1 1; 0 0 1]);
...
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually incorrect because an area plot adds the two vectors. If you add the line plots plot(xData,Rain_Min,'k','linewidth',2)
plot(xData,Rain_Max,'k','linewidth',2) then you will see what I mean @natan

Comment: @user2861089 - You didn't tell us what it's supposed to correctly look like.  We aren't mind readers, nor are we clairvoyant. Please tell us what this graph is supposed to look like.

Comment: @rayryeng Sorry for not being more clear - I just want to shade the area between the two lines (see my second figure above). As I understand it, an area plot doesn't do this because it stacks both vectors (thus adding them) rather than simply shading the area...

Comment: @user2861089 natan's figure looks like it's shading in between the two lines.  Also, natan said that you can use `area` **with a twist**, which implies that he is using it in a way that is not normally done with the function, but he is still achieving your goal.  I don't see how this is incorrect.  Why do you have to add the two plots together?

Comment: @rayryeng OK, let's just say I have the following plot: Rain_Max = [10 12 15 10 14];
Rain_Min = [5 1 4 6 7];
xData = [1 2 3 4 5];
area(xData,[Rain_Min(:) , Rain_Max(:)]); hold on
colormap([1 1 1; 0 0 1]); This is not what I want because Rain_Max(1)=10 not 15. This is adding them together instead of simply shading an area.

Comment: @user2861089 - You only said you wanted to shade the areas in between the lines.  You didn't specify that you wanted to do data analysis after.

Comment: @rayryeng I do just want to shade the area between two lines, without moving the lines... I guess I will just use something like Rain_Max_2 = Rain_Max-Rain_Min

Comment: wow... a lot of comments while I was gone for dinner :)  anything else that I can answer here? (I did edit this to be more accurate, though I just wanted to demonstrate the principle of using `area`)